# GCM not working with a corporate google account

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I have a GCM notification implementation which works perfectly. But, if I change the sender Id /(project ID) from my Google account to a corporate account/business account which is tied to Google, the GCM notification message is sent successfully from the server, but is not received at the receiver device.

I would like to know , if there are any specific prerequisites to be followed for GCM implementation using a corporate Google account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know , if there are any specific prerequisites to be
>   followed for GCM implementation using a corporate Google account.

The answer is no. I finish just now the implementation of GCM with a Google App (corporate) account and I just follow the standard guidelines as described in the [Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Your problem should come from another place but we need more informations to help you. It could appear because your client application has to register again when you change the `SENDER_ID`.